# Can I connect two taps of a tapped transformer together to make a center tapped transformer?

Tags: transformer

I want to get two 8 V AC from this transformer which is outputting 0, 8, 16, 24 V / 1 A.

[image]

Comment: Not like that...

Comment: @BrianDrummond May I please know your suggestion, is it other than what Neil_UK suggested?

Comment: It is exactly what Neil suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. That connection creates a short circuit on the secondary.

If you're lucky, it will draw enough current to blow your primary fuse. If you're unlucky, it won't blow the fuse, and will overheat the transformer.

You already have the solution with that transformer. Use the 8 V tap as the centre tap between 0 and 16 V, and ignore the 24 V tap.

Comment: ^^^   This!    "You already have the solution with that transformer. Use the 8 V tap as the centre tap between 0 and 16 V, and ignore the 24 V tap"

Answer (score 3):

No. That would equal to shorting out a 8VAC coil.